# jquery table sorting

Tags: jquery

I have created a table dynamically. The table loads data form database. This is the following code.

```
$('#artistinfo').empty();
$('#artistinfo').append('<table  id="transactions" class="partner" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:90%;" />');
$('#artistinfo table').append(
' <tr class="thead"><th valign="top">Artist</th><th valign="top">Release</th> <th valign="top">Score</th>  </tr>');
$('#artistinfo table').append('<tr>' +
'<td>' + artistname + '</td>' +
'<td>' + releasename + '</td>' +
'<td>' + score+ '</td>' +
'</tr>'
);
```

I want to sort the table by each coloume. Is it possible by jquery?

For examaple, score is a number type. I want to sort it ascending or desc

Comment: What have your tried? i can google this for you and the first hit tells me the sollution (http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: [DataTables](http://datatables.net) is a popular plugin

Answer (score 0):

Using only jQuery it'd be quite expensive to do what you want as this functionality does not come by default. Instead of reinventing the wheel I'd go through these plugins: [**DataTables**](http://datatables.net/) and [**jqGrid**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). These two offer quite good API's and extensive functionality and it seems they are also designed to provide good performance.

Of course, there are far more plugins to display a grid and you could try Google.